# Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so

Tags: gnome

20.04 recently updated.

Getting this error starting xscreensaver-demo:

```
 Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is just a warning:

> $ xscreensaver-demo
>
> (xscreensaver-demo:2690): libglade-WARNING **: 09:55:45.071: Could not load support for >`gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It is some kind of leftover from the past. You can simply ignore it.

Comment: Strange. I noticed the message because the screensaver was not working, and the management window did not open. Usually the opening of the management window hid the message I suppose or gave me no cause to examine the terminal output. I was having other issues (that machine is a bit touchy) so I rebooted and indeed -- just as you say.